# how to call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath from UIButton cell item iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have a custom cell having a `UIButton` and a `UITextField`. Now when i click on the button i want to capture the `indexpath.row` in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. but when i click on the button `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is not called. I know button will capture the click. but curious to know any workaround? any smart way guys.

Please guide

thanks.

[image]

Comment: you can use tag property of the button to get the index path.

Comment: @suhit look at my reply to below comment.

Comment: You can use the delegate-protocol method instead to perform the action in viewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to calling didSelect Method from button click event try in to your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` index just setting button tag is **indexPath.row** like:

```
     cell.btnInvite.tag=indexPath.row;
     [cell.btnInvite addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCommentClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)btnCommentClick:(UIButton*)sender
{
  NSLog(@"frined add %d",sender.tag); //now do you stuff that you want you have selected cell index as a button tag.

}
```

Comment: i tried this but inside the action of button i am always receiving the very last index path.row. i am trying to delete the text field on click of the button by fetching the index row but it always deletes the last row. any idea?

Comment: i wasn't using sender.tag..my bad..now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add button's target in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     //Continue with your code...

 [cell.actionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
}


- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    // Cast Sender to UIButton
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    // Find Point in Superview
    CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];

    // Infer Index Path
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];

    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: look at my reply to above comment.